# Why can't I get the inverse of matrix using excel?

Tags: excel

I watched this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gtE-PZBi70

and followed step by step to find the inverse of a matrix.

It turns out that when I click control+shift+enter I got nothing but a meaningful parenthesis `)`

Here it is before control+shift+enter and after selecting

[image]

after control+shift+enter

[image]

why?

help me please

Comment: What did you enter or perhaps more correctly, what did you do different? Provide a complete example of what you did.

Comment: Seems like you put a newline inside your formula and that right parenthesis is on its own line.  Pull down the bottom of the formula to expand it and I'm guessing that's what you'll see.  Delete what you have and try it again.

Comment: @TimWilliams you are right. Then what do I do? now wherever I point on the screen there is a green rectangle following, like indicating that I should select something.

Comment: Hit Esc to get out of edit mode

Comment: @TimWilliams ohh everything disappear.. there is no inverse matrix :( I should have not click Esc, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered the matrix example as you stated and minverse() for the array works when entered with cntrl+shift+enter.

See:

[image]

I can't see this being an excel version issue as you show the minverse function.

Edit, based on the comments below, here are the steps to achieve the result:

1. select the range of cells for the resulting matrix
2. enter "=minverse(",
3. then (mouse) select the range,
4. then cmnd+T to add the $ and close the bracket,
5. then ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: I entered "=minverse(" then mouse selected the range, then cmnd+T to add the $, closed the bracket, then ctrl+shift+enter...

Comment: Well after doing what you said you did I got only the first entry of the inverse matrix i.e. `.37692308`. why?

Comment: @Isa Did you select the entire range for the future matrix before entering the formula?